# UITableViewCells not highlighting on touch

Tags: iphone, select, uitableview, highlighting

I'm subclassing UITableViewCell and adding two subviews (image, UILabel).

When the row is touched. There's no cell highlighting indicating the cell was selected.

I'm pretty sure I missed something, not sure how to handle highlighting for subclassed cell.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code it is hard to give you a specific answer of how to fix your subclass of UITableViewCell. It could be something as complex as overriding a method that deals with the selection or render to something as simple as when you where in Interface Builder you forgot to select the highlight color for your UILabel.

All I can do with the limited information provided is point you to Apple's documentation on [Subclassing UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12).

If this doesn't help please post your subclass code for the community to review and I am sure myself or someone can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks. The culprit was a UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone I missed.